# How to get the attribute value of the tag by attribute name with HTMLDocument object in VBA?

Tags: html, vba, parsing, dom

I want to get all attribute values of the tag ("meta") with attribute name ("charset").
As the result of my macro I expected to see:

`1/4 element "charset" = UTF-8`

but I get:

`1/2 element "charset" = UTF-8`
`2/2 element "charset" = UTF-8`

Where I made a mistake?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ParseAnAttr()

    Dim MetaTags As String, i As Integer, j As Integer

    MetaTags = ""
    MetaTags = MetaTags & "<meta charset=""UTF-8""/> "
    MetaTags = MetaTags & "<meta name=""ResourceLoaderDynamicStyles"" content=""1""/> "
    MetaTags = MetaTags & "<script type=""text/javascript""> "
    MetaTags = MetaTags & "<meta name=""generator"" content=""Media""/> "
    MetaTags = MetaTags & "<meta name=""referrer"" content=""origin""/> "

    Dim objHtml As Object
    Set objHtml = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    With objHtml
        .Open
        .write MetaTags
        .Close
    End With

    Dim objElements As Object, objElement As Object
    Set objElements = objHtml.getElementsByTagName("meta")

    For Each objElement In objElements
        If objElement > 0 Then i = i + 1
    Next objElement

    For Each objElement In objElements
        For j = 0 To i - 1
            If objElement.Charset <> "" Then
                Debug.Print j + 1 & "/" & i & " element ""charset"" = " & objElement.Charset
            End If
        Next j
    Next objElement

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unclosed `<script>` element in the middle of your `<meta>` tags. Is that intentional? And `objElement.Charset` is not doing what you think.

Try this:

```
Sub ParseAnAttr()

    Dim MetaTags As String, att
    Dim objHtml As Object
    Dim objElements As Object, objElement As Object, j As Long

    MetaTags = "<meta charset=""UTF-8""/> " & _
        "<meta name=""ResourceLoaderDynamicStyles"" content=""1""/> " & _
        "<script type=""text/javascript"" ></script> " & _
        "<meta name=""generator"" content=""Media""/> " & _
        "<meta name=""referrer"" content=""origin""/> "

    Set objHtml = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    With objHtml
        .Open
        .write MetaTags
        .Close
        Set objElements = .getElementsByTagName("meta")
    End With

    j = 1
    For Each objElement In objElements
        att = objElement.getAttribute("charset")
        If att <> "" Then
            Debug.Print objElement.outerHTML
            Debug.Print j + 1 & "/" & objElements.Length & " element ""charset"" = " & att
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next objElement

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Tim Williams! No, it is not intentional, but it would be great to skip that mistakes if it is possible. There is should be `Debug.Print j` instead of `Debug.Print j + 1` to get the correct index number.

Comment: If add "<meta charset=""UTF-7""/>" in MetaTags as the sixth meta tag, then `Debug.Print objElement.outerHTML` doesn't work correctly.